# How do I get the alternate "g" glyph on Open Sans?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'm trying to specify the alternate "g" glyph provided by `opensans` (using `pdflatex`) but can't find instructions anywhere in the documentation on how to do that. I'd like to use alternate throughout my document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `pdflatex` you can't, unless you create a new set of fonts from the TrueType version. Fonts for `pdflatex` have only 256 slots and no possibility of defining a variant. One could, in principle, just create new `.pfb` files and use the metrics for the “normal g”, but it would be very tough work.

It's easy with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, as the alternate “g” is in stylistic set 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,StylisticSet=2]{OpenSans}
\newfontfamily{\normalg}[Ligatures=TeX]{OpenSans} % the same font without the normal g

\begin{document}

A g \textbf{g} \textit{g}

\normalg % show the normal g

A g \textbf{g} \textit{g}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry: `pdflatex`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You don't, unless you create a whole new set of fonts.

Comment: Bummer. I'm stuck with `pdflatex`, at least in the context I'm asking.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Sorry, but it's something that the font developer should deal with. Maybe you can ask for this feature: if the "generating machine" is good, it wouldn't be really difficult.

Comment: Actually, I think the glyph is probably in the type1 fonts and the metrics are certainly in the afm files. So you would not need to generate additional pfb files. What you are missing are *TeX* font metrics (tfm files) and (optionally) virtual fonts (vf files). At least, I'm assuming g.alt is likely the alternate g, just from reading the afm for the regular font. Still means essentially generating additional fonts, mind - just not type1.